# Ansible something went wrong with RuntimeError

Tags: python, vagrant, ansible

Ansible version:

```
ansible 2.3.0.0
  configured module search path = Default w/o overrides
  python version = 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) [GCC 5.4.0 20160609]
```

Want to run a playbook. Target is Vagrant. Sometimes when I run "Install Python" task:

```
- name:
  yum:
    name: python
    state: present
```

I get this error:

```
fatal: [192.168.0.1]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "Warning: Permanently added '192.168.0.1' (ECDSA) to the list of known hosts.\r\nConnection to 192.168.0.1 closed.\r\n", "module_stdout": "Trac
eback (most recent call last):\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_l93xpj/ansible_module_yum.py\", line 249, in <module>\r\n    from ansible.module_utils.urls import fetch_url\r\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_l93xpj/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/
urls.py\", line 152, in <module>\r\n  File \"/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/requests/__init__.py\", line 74, in <module>\r\n    raise RuntimeError('Requests dependency \\'chardet\\' must be version >= 3.0.2, < 3.1.0!')\r\nRuntimeError:
 Requests dependency 'chardet' must be version >= 3.0.2, < 3.1.0!\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 0}
```

When I check the `192.168.0.1`, the Python version:

> Python 2.7.5

Why do I get this error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> Requests dependency 'chardet' must be version >= 3.0.2, < 3.1.0!
> ```
>
> Why got this error?

Because your target machine doesn't have package `chardet`, with version number equal or greater than 3.0.2, installed.

Comment: I checked both local and vagrant(192.168.0.1) with: `pip freeze | grep chardet`, all of them got `chardet==3.0.3`.

Comment: You might be checking different Python than Ansible runs.

Comment: Even I use `pyenv` installed a new python version, a very fresh pip list. The result was the same. I think the problem was not the machine has or not `charset`.

Comment: What can I do for you?

Comment: I know the reason! The host `192.168.0.1` has a default old `chardet` version: `chardet==2.2.1`. Remove it all works well.